# If path not taken on parameter

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am getting the message in Karma that the "if path not taken" for each of these 4 private methods.

I have several unit tests that call each of these private methods with various values, and many of these set the `isReq` property to true or false, so I'm not sure why it thinks that there's any path I'm not testing.  Any ideas?

[image: if path not taken?]

And here's a pic of some of my relevant test code:

[image]

Comment: Instead of pasting screenshots, you should show the actual code as text.

Comment: If i did that, it wouldn't be obvious where Istanbul was reporting that an If path wasn't taken.

Answer (score 4):

SOLUTION FOUND!

I discovered what my problem was: I am calling the public method which provides a default value on the boolean.  Then the public method is calling one private method which is calling another which is calling another.  The initial public method sets a default value which is passed to the first private method.  So from that point forward, there is always a value being passed in!  It's never using the default values supplied because there's always a value passed into the private methods.

So the solution was merely to remove the default supplied values for the private methods as these are never being used.

I just wanted to post this here in case it helps someone else who has struggled with this same concept as i have.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that `getUploadedFormGroup` is returning falsy and so `getUploadedArray` is never being called.